# Shower floor is in bad shape - what options do we have?

Tags: flooring, shower, tile

We've asked for a quick estimate from the guy doing our laminate, and he said it's not worth it to re-grout. He also said there's no way to just remove the old tile, since the floor is slightly water damaged.

Short of ripping out everything, something he says will cost upwards of $2,000 + materials, do we have any other options here? We just want a clean shower floor.

[image: exhibit a]
[image: exhibit b]

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and make party with some mould exterminator like chlor. No matter how long you will use this shower,  mould is biological hazard and you are risking the health of yourself and any other person that uses this shower.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend a quick-fix.  There's probably a fair amount of mold between the tile and the pan, and if that's the case, you don't want to attempt the fix yourself unless you're qualified for mold mitigation.

Comment: Yeah, for me, it seems like mold is the real problem, not the little gaps.